# How can I answer the question "what do you hope to achieve during your studies at University X?"

Tags: phd, statement-of-purpose

Currently I am writing a Statement of Purpose for a PhD application, and they asked me this question:

> What you hope to achieve during your studies at the XX university?

How I can answer this question, I need some ideas.

Comment: Well, what *do* you hope to achieve during your PhD?

Comment: If you really have no idea what you hope to achieve, why are you applying?

Comment: _How I can answer this question_ — Honestly and directly.

Answer (score 2):

At this point, you can't really say what you will achieve or accomplish, exactly.  I mean, if you knew all that already, you kind of wouldn't need to go there to study, would you?

What I did was I described my fantasies, of what I wanted to study, which I hoped I would find there.  At the time, I was working as a COBOL programmer.  It was tedious.  Once in a while there was a fun logical challenge, but mostly I was pulling data from the student database at a community college, and writing tedious code to format the results in a nice report for a college administrator.

One fantasy was that I would write a program that would generate the tedious COBOL code.

That's not what I ended up doing once I was in the grad program.

But that was okay.

I don't remember what my other fantasy was, but I think it was something that I imagined as a result of programming a spline fit for a numerical methods class I took as an undergrad.  That was a really fun project and I wanted to do more of that kind of programming.

Just write about what sorts of things you'd like to learn more about when you are in a grad program.

Answer (score 0):

> How I can answer this question, I need some ideas.

You can *answer the question*. What do you hope to achieve? Why are you doing this? Why this university? What direction do you see yourself heading in?

Critically, if you do not at least have an inkling of what your answer to this question is already, it's time for some genuine self-reflection as to whether or not pursuing a PhD at this point is a good idea.